# Using SQL to query numbers that have more than tenths decimal place

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, rounding

I have a text field that contains numbers. Some of these numbers have two digits after the decimal and others only one.

Is there a SQL expression to query out only the numbers containing the hundredths values?

My end goal is to use the "round" function to round these isolated numbers to the tenths place.

RDBMS used: sql-server

Comment: Simply do cast(value as decimal(11,1))

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Which is your `RDBMS`? What is the datatype of these `numbers` you are getting? `varchar\int`

Comment: @Praveen the RDBMS is SQL Server and the data types are 'varchar'.

Comment: @Sippy I haven't tried anything yet because I have been unsuccessful in my research.

Comment: @jarlh thanks I will give that a shot.

Comment: Currently your text field doesn't contain numbers, it contains strings which look like numeric values and there's no kind of `ROUND` function for strings. Simply change the datatype of this column to a `DECIMAL` matching your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `charindex` and `reverse`.

```
select val 
from tbl
where charindex('.', reverse(val)) = 3
```

**Demo**

```
declare @tbl table(val varchar(50))
insert into @tbl select '11.02'
insert into @tbl select '411.0'
insert into @tbl select '11.44'
insert into @tbl select '1144.03'
insert into @tbl select '1441.5'

select val 
from @tbl
where charindex('.', reverse(val)) = 3

output:
11.02
11.44
1144.03
```

Comment: This includes product specific functionality, and no dbms is specified. At least specify which dbms it works with.

Comment: @jarlh `Matt` mentioned `DBMS` used is `sql-server`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that comment.